# expand/collapse zk panel with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zk

I wanna click on a ZK's borderlayout(collapsible "East" OR "North" OR...) to open it temporarily with javascript.
what should I do?

thanks in advance buddies.

**UPDATE:**

When it is closed, by clicking on the closed border **area**(not on the Open **ICON**) **(Look at the cursor's position in the picture)** it will be open temporarily. I want a closed borderLayout and open it like that, with javascript/jquery.

the picture:
[image]

Comment: I wanna million pounds, but that's about as likely to happen as someone getting an accepted answer from you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i checked and he has accepted the answers where there were answers to accepted! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose ,here I provide another example for this.
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/bk3jop/2-Close-border-layout-panel-by-javascript

```
<script>
    function openNorth(){
      var widget = zk.Widget.$("$mynorth"); //Using the pattern for $ + ID to select a ZK widget. 

       if(!widget.isOpen()){
         try{
           widget.doClick_({
             domTarget:widget.$n('colled')  
           });
         }catch(e){ //ignore unhandled exception.
         }
       }

    }    
  </script>
```

Anyway , it's more like a hack.

For more details you could reference to 
https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zul/src/archive/web/js/zul/layout/LayoutRegion.js

```
doClick_: function (evt) {
        var target = evt.domTarget;
        switch (target) {
        case this.$n('btn'):
        case this.$n('btned'):
        case this.$n('splitbtn'):
            if (this._isSlide || zk.animating()) return;
            if (this.$n('btned') == target) {
                var s = this.$n('real').style;
                s.visibility = "hidden";
                s.display = "";
                this._syncSize(true);
                s.visibility = "";
                s.display = "none";
            }
            this.setOpen(!this._open);
            break;
        case this.$n('colled'):                 
            if (this._isSlide) return;
            this._isSlide = true;
            var real = this.$n('real'),
                s = real.style;
            s.visibility = "hidden";
            s.display = "";
            this._syncSize();
            this._original = [s.left, s.top];
            this._alignTo();
            s.zIndex = 100;

            if (this.$n('btn'))
                this.$n('btn').style.display = "none"; 
            s.visibility = "";
            s.display = "none";
            zk(real).slideDown(this, {
                anchor: this.sanchor,
                afterAnima: this.$class.afterSlideDown
            });
            break;
        }
        this.$supers('doClick_', arguments);        
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Get the widget from ZK client engine.

2.call setOpen(true) or setOpen(false)

Here's a sample for this, and also you could test it on ZK fiddle platform.

http://zkfiddle.org/sample/bk3jop/1-Close-border-layout-panel-by-javascript

```
<zk xmlns:w="client">

  <script>
    function closeNorth(){
      var widget = zk.Widget.$("$mynorth"); //Using the pattern for $ + ID to select a ZK widget. 
      widget.setOpen(false);

    }
    function openNorth(){
      var widget = zk.Widget.$("$mynorth"); //Using the pattern for $ + ID to select a ZK widget. 
      widget.setOpen(true);

    }    
  </script>
  <button label="click me to close it" w:onClick="closeNorth();" />          
  <button label="click me to open it" w:onClick="openNorth();"  />    

  <borderlayout >
    <north id="mynorth" title="North" maxsize="300" size="50%" splittable="true" collapsible="true">
          <div>
           Test .... <textbox />
          </div>
    </north>
  </borderlayout>

</zk>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I wanted to open it temporarily. When we click on the closed border area(not the circle ICON)(when it is closed) it opens it temporarily and when we click on the outside of the borderlayout, it closes itself.

Comment: Could you explain your use-case more clear , I believe we could do most case you want.  But first , I have to know what you want to do. :)

Comment: Isn't that a existing feature ? Maybe I should ask your ZK version first.  Reference the video I take for the demo. http://screencast.com/t/YnKndjSz7f

Comment: The operation in the taken video is exactly what I need, but by clicking the button that you made(in the fiddle's), border get open completely(not temporarily).

Comment: But that's a existing feature? Or you want a button to click and do the same thing ? :) Let me think about it....